# Оптимизация кода, грамотность кода

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, оптимизация

Столкнулся с проблемой, проект резко развернули в сторону Биг Дата, на вход стали приходить массивы весами >300МБ и мягко говоря на вебе, таблицы стали загружаться более затруднительно, но все же они загружаются, беда в другом, функционал позволяет сохранять все эти данные в БД в формате JSON (array), чтобы потом можно было их так-же отобразить в табличке.
Собственно момент с сохранением и вызывает трудности. Я грубо говоря делаю foreach по всем данным, передаю в PHP (o_O), там произвожу манипуляции с группировками и прочие действия, по итогу результат преобразований передаю в модель с updateOrCreate (Laravel) таблички, чтобы заполнить одну колонку данными. Сохранение с базу 2к строк занимает 2.4 секунды, но при 10к строк мы ложимся на лопатки со словами BadGateway502, сеть перегружена напрочь.
Не верю чтобы разного рода сортировка данных в PHP занимает уйму времени и сожрала всю память (set_time_limit стоит 0, memory_limit стоит -1).
Может мне стоит производить все работы с сортировкой данных на стороне клиента, а в insert передавать готовый гигантский массив?
Как можно оптимизировать (реструктуризировать) код чтобы обработать такой объем данных ?
Прошу помощи, может кто бы сталкивался с подобными объемами

Comment: Подумываю над реализацией передачи массива частями в PHP и каждый раз ждать результат с ответом на выполнение. Есть на этот счет комментарии ?

Comment: Первый вопрос, который приходит в голову в таких случаях: А почему нельзя порциями отображать пагинацией или ленивой загрузкой?

Comment: @EzioMercer Отвечу. Мне многие об этом говорят, но функционал таблиц велик, скажем добавить сложение колонок, где результат сразу подгружается и соотносится к каждой строке, еще функция пропусков, которая удаляет пустые значения в строках, эти функции требуют область видимости всего grid (таблицы).

Comment: Это всё должно происходить запорсами. Нажал кнопку, отправил команду, бек сделал нужные вычисления и отправил обратно порцию того что надо. Клиент не должен заниматься всем этим. Когда делают автодополнение вы же не загружаете всевозможные данные, а потом на клиенете их фильтруете. Каждое изменение инпута - это новый запрос

Comment: @EzioMercer я с вами согласен, и понимаю это, именно так и реализовано, функция Сохранения подразумевает сбор того что мы имеем в таблице и с помощью axios передает в контроллер, где и происходит update/insert таблицы этим гигантским массивом. Меня волнует этап передачи, а именно момент с тем, что сеть не вывозит подобные массивы в >300МБ.

Comment: Мы друг друга не понимаем, кажется) Момента с передачей таких больших данных впринципе не должно быть, вот к чему я. Допустим надо убрать пустые строки: нажали на кнопку, отправили запрос на бэк (имею ввиду только команду, без лишних данных, ну в случае с пагинацей и номер текущей страницы), бэк принимает команду очистить строки, убирает строки сам или делает новый запрос в БД с соответствующими параметрами (не силён в бэке, потому не знаю что именно там делается) и отправляет новые данные на фронт (вернее ту часть, которая соответсвует номеру страницы типа с 50 по 100 сторки)

Comment: Я вас услышал. Это самое верное решение. К сожалению я не смогу средствами БД найти эти данные или как-то их восстановить, это сохранение нового массива.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137357/discussion-between-eziomercer-and--).

Answer (score 0):

Тяжелые задачи выполняйте ассинхронно или на кроне. Не заставляйте клиента ждать.

В зависимости от целей использования данных возможно нужно переходить на другую СУБД колоночную (например ClickHouse) или NoSql (например MongoDb).

Comment: Я полагаю что тут больше проблема в больших объемах данных и нужно решение, которое бы могло как-то облегчить передачу данных клиент(400МБ)->php->Oracle->клиент.
Полагаю что сеть от подобных потоков передачи помирает разом.
Опять же с точки зрения оптимизации делаю попытки передачи в контроллер кусочки массива по 300 строк и await функция которая подождет когда все куски запишутся, но не уверен вовсе в результате

Comment: Как у вас изначально на клиенте оказались такие большие объемы данных? Они загружают CSV файлы или текстовые файлы таких размеров, что ли?

Comment: Изначально, на основе выбранных параметром формируется автоматически запрос из БД и его результат декодится в JSON и передается в таблицу